# Formula to check existing duplicate value on field in Process Builder

Tags: formula, opportunity, process-builder, custom-field, opportunity-lineitem

I have a process builder process that populates a field on the opportunity level with one present on the opportunity product. The code is as follows:

```
(AND(NOT(ISBLANK([OpportunityLineItem].OppProdCustomField1__c)))
|| ISCHANGED([OpportunityLineItem].OppProdCustomField1__c ))

&&(NOT(CONTAINS([OpportunityLineItem].Opportunity.Description, [OpportunityLineItem].OppProdCustomField1__c)))
```

The process saves fine without the syntax errors but it will not populate at all!
If I remove the second part it works fine **BUT I need the value in the Opportunity Field to be unique - it must not add to it if the same figure is there (no duplicates)**

Second part being:

```
&&(NOT(CONTAINS([OpportunityLineItem].Opportunity.OppCustomField1__c, [OpportunityLineItem].OppProdCustomField1__c)))
```

Comment: Whats the relation bw `Opportunity.OppCustomField1__c` and `OpportunityLineItem.OppProdCustomField1__c`?

Comment: The one on opportunity level is actually a standard field (Description) the one on opportunity product is a text custom field. I have updated the question above also...

Comment: Why are you checking if the field (Description) has text from the `OppLineItem.CustomField__c`? I wanna know the business requirement here.

Comment: I want to avoid the PB populating the Description with the same value of the OppLineItem.CustomField__c if it is already in there (to avoid having 10s of duplicate OppLineItem.CustomField__c values in there since it runs when the record is created OR when it is Updated)

Comment: Have you check the values residing in both of these fields?

Comment: What do you mean? How would I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54739/discussion-between-mahmood-and-user2326637).

Answer (score 2):

`Description` field on [**Opportunity**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm) object is a **TextArea** field and you can't refer them in formulas.

There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrhEAAS) to provide support for certain functions support on text area fields. You can upvote that.

Comment: Waw a 7 years old Idea, still in status not planned :p